# Automatically namespace a page in Dokuwiki

Tags: wiki, dokuwiki

Is it possible to automatically namespace the links in a page (with the pagename), in Dokuwiki?

i.e., If I create a page [[projects]] in the global namespace, and put any further links inside it

```
e.g.  [[project1]], [[project2]]
```

these pages should automatically be under the 'projects' namespace.

Is this possible (either natively, or through a plugin) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which does what I was trying to achieve.

Any link in a page, which is meant as belonging to the subject of that page, I link as follows

```
[[.subject:]]
```

This automatically makes it a link to

```
current_namespace:subject:start
```

Having changed my landing page of a namespace from 'start' to 'index', I get a behavior close to what I was looking for in the first place, i.e., a link

```
[[.topic1:]]
```

in a page

```
[[project1:index]],
```

will point to

```
[[project1:topic1:index]]
```